# PHP Display Data in Grid Based on Templates

Tags: php, css

I want to display all the data from the database in a grid view based on templates that I use but the problem is I cannot put it in a view that I want which is I want it to look like this.

[image] [image] [image] [image]

[image] [image] [image] [image]

and so on.

This is what I have tried so far

```
    <!-- First Photo Grid-->
    <?php
    $sql ="SELECT * from design";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($row > 0)
      {
      while ($res=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
       {
    ?>
  
 <div class="w3-row-padding w3-padding-16 w3-center" id="item">
   <?php echo '<div class="w3-quarter">'; ?>
      <table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
      <tr><td>
      <img src="cat/<?=$res['image']?>" style="width:100%">
      <h3><?php echo $res['type']; ?></h3>
      <p><?php echo $res['designid']; ?></p>
      <p>RM <?php echo $res['price']; ?></p>
      <button type="submit" href="home-edit.php?designid=<?php echo $res['designid']; ?>" onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">EDIT ITEM</button>
      </td></tr>   </table>

      <?php 
         }
         }   ?>
 <?php echo '</div>'; ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want put your 4 items in every row you can use a variable $counter for counting rows in while block and control items with If

try this instead

```
    <!-- First Photo Grid-->
    <?php
    $sql ="SELECT * from design";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($row > 0)
      {
    $counter=0;
      while ($res=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
       {
    $counter++
    ?>
  
 <div class="w3-row-padding w3-padding-16 w3-center" id="item">
   <?php echo '<div class="w3-quarter">'; ?>
      <table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
      <tr><td>
      <img src="cat/<?=$res['image']?>" style="width:100%">
      <h3><?php echo $res['type']; ?></h3>
      <p><?php echo $res['designid']; ?></p>
      <p>RM <?php echo $res['price']; ?></p>
      <button type="submit" href="home-edit.php?designid=<?php echo 
 $res['designid']; ?>" 
   onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'" 
   style="width:auto;">EDIT ITEM</button>
      </td>

 <?php
    if ($counter % 4 ==0)
    echo("</tr></tr>");
   } //while
   } // if
   if ($counter % 4 !=0)
    echo("</tr>");
  ?>
 </table> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried it but the result keep inserting at the next row instead of the next column. I also tried to change `echo ("</tr></tr>");` to `echo ("<td></td>");` and it's just the same. I also try and error other things but i don't know where it goes wrong.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is wrong echo ("</tr></tr>"). Please write echo ("</tr><tr>").